# What is the difference between BBWebview and GDWebview?

Tags: android, blackberry, blackberry-android, blackberry-dynamics

[GDWebview](https://developer.blackberry.com/devzone/files/blackberry-dynamics/android/classcom_1_1good_1_1gd_1_1widget_1_1_g_d_web_view.html) has been in the SDK for a while. [BBWebview](https://docs.blackberry.com/en/development-tools/blackberry-dynamics-sdk-android/9_2/blackberry-dynamics-sdk-android-devguide/Integrating-optional-features/Using-the-BBWebView-library) is newly referenced in SDK 9.2. They seem to both extend from `android.webkit.Webview` Is there a difference between these classes? Are there use cases that each are intended for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that both extend android.webkit.Webview GDWebView. GDWebView provides blocking of copy and paste based on the BlackBerry Dynamics Data Leakage Prevention configuration within the BlackBerry Dynamics Policy assigned to the from through BlackBerry UEM.

BBWebView includes the copy and paste protection mentioned above. It also adds support for BlackBerry Dynamics networking and stores cookies using the BlackBerry Dynamics secure file system. Refer to the [Architecture Overview](https://developers.blackberry.com/us/en/resources/get-started/blackberry-dynamics-getting-started.html?platform=android#step-1) section for more detail on BlackBerry Dynamics networking.

BBWebView is within a library that was created based on the open source [BlackBerry Dynamics WebView client sample](https://github.com/blackberry/BlackBerry-Dynamics-Android-Samples/tree/master/AndroidWebView).